# mootools and prototype conflict

Tags: mootools, prototypejs, conflict

this is my code it keeps not work , if i remove the prototype script file , mootools work and if i remove the mootools prototype works !! this is code :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/mootools.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/imageMenu.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/prototype.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

            window.addEvent('domready', function(){
                var myMenu = new ImageMenu($$('#imageMenu a'),{openWidth:310, border:2, onOpen:function(e,i){alert(e);}});
            });
</script>
```

Its important to mention that when i try once , prototype worked together with MT but Ajax.Updater in prototype still not work .

i did check most of topics here about the problem but still lose !

Comment: Short answer: It's impossible to use these two frameworks together as both of them extend Natives. Period.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you'd even **want** to use prototype and mootools together. This would certainly qualify as misuse of frameworks... pick ONE and stick with it. If you can't choose between one or the other, start with the base assumption that you even need a framework at all, then decide from there which one suits your needs. Using one (or several) simply for the sake of having it is a bad plan.

Both frameworks accomplish their functionality by extending DOM, so it isn't a surprise that there are conflicts. Both use `$` as an entry point for their extended functionality. The amount of functionality duplication you get when you stack frameworks nearly precludes using them in conjunction, never mind the additional overhead in loading tons of code you don't need.

All that said, you can check out [this article](http://mootools.net/blog/2009/06/22/the-dollar-safe-mode/). This is mootools' recommendation for compatibility/conflict resolution with other frameworks. You will note that in the first paragraph of the article, the author gives the same warning I have here - don't stack frameworks. There are very few, highly specific circumstances where this is your only choice, otherwise you seriously need to consider why you're taking this approach.

Comment: thank you Chris , I agree with you about to stick with only one FW but the problem here that this move (Phatfusion Image Menu) only made with mootools , also i check it is made by JQuery as well , but not with prototype . i dod check that article but did now know how to use it with my mootools fucntion , i have tow $ in the function so to replace both of them to document.id ? it's won't work !! also i did try to use the JQuery version of (Phatfusion Image Menu) and to use No.Conflict but also didn't make it :(

Comment: What I am saying, then, is that you should find a different menu system that uses the framework you are already using and provides the functionality you need. If you can't find it, you should either a) reconsider frameworks or b) reconsider what functionality you need out of your menu. If you aren't finding pre-built prototype scripts that suit you, why not move to mootools all together?  If I drive a Dodge pickup truck and I need a part, I don't buy Ford accessories - I don't even look at them because they won't fit my truck. Likewise, when you are using prototype, don't shop mootools.